# Youtube iframe video not showing in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, youtube

I've created a template for one of the pages on my wordpress site & I've added a couple of youtube videos within an iframe but they're not showing. On a blank index.html file that is hosted on my computer is it shown but not when I upload it to Wordpress. When I inspect the page the iframe is there (shown below) [image]
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<p class="reveal1">
Some more text.
  <div class="video-container1" align="center">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfHXbPv9cUg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</p>
<div id="more1" align="center" title="View More">
  <img src="http://www.blackballad.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/drop.png" width="20px" height="20px">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#more1").click(function(){
      $(".reveal1").slideToggle("slow");
      $(".video-container1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Console errors:

[image]

Comment: did you check the console for errors?

Comment: @Pamblam yes, but not too sure how they can help me. I've added them for you to see :)

Comment: are you running the under the file:/// protocol or are you on a server?

Comment: also, your urls are wrong.. `public_html` needs to be removed from a few of those resources you're loading, that explains some of the 404s

Comment: looks like you have an adblocker too.. anyway, none of those errors are related to youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the iframes yourself. Instead, use [the JavaScript published in the iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)